# Push notification appears after one user messages another user using firebase and xcode

Tags: xcode, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I were to make a messaging app which would involve a user recieving a notification after being messaged by another user, how could i go about setting up the notifications in such a way where they are sent after the message is sent by the user who sent it. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome thank you.

P.S. I am using cloud messaging

Comment: Show a turorial from firebase that you followed. Show what you have done. It’s difficult for us to make assumptions what you read and what you didn’t and what did and what you didn’t with your project/code

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough what I meant, I'm not following a specific tutorial, hypothetically if I were to have a messaging app in which two users can message each other. I want a push notification to be sent to the user recieving the message so they are notified they have a message from another user. What I am more asking for is if there is a tutorial/video or documentation i could take a look at to show me how to set up the push notification in such a way. Thanks

Comment: Did you search for “ ios push notification tutorial” in Google? I see plenty of good respurces.FWIW the site isn’t meant to be used to ask for tutorials. Everyone can google that. You should with questions about how you faced errors or problems with your setup

Comment: I did search that into google however it just shows me how to manually send notifications to all of your users, however, I want a notification to pop up only if a user has received a message from another user. I would show you my code but I doubt it would help because I dont even know how to get started. Thanks again.

Comment: Essentially I want to know how to have a user's action(In my case sending a message) result in a notification being sent out to the user receiving it.(Using firebase)

Comment: Did you start doing any of your code? Your question needs to detailed i.e. have some code and actual configuration and or at least some fake code. Currently you have none. And that’s not a way to use the site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask but also try this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/ . Having that said, you should be able to search for ‘send ios push notification using firebase’ and go through the first 10 links and see what they offer and then add more details. No one here is gonna tell you what you need to do a-z

Comment: I found a similar question to mine which has been answered and it was what I was looking for I don't know how It didn't show up in my past google searches. I now know I most likely worded my question wrongly but thank you for your time anyway and next time ill make sure to provide some code. I'm still pretty new to this stuff so thanks for helping me out once again.

Comment: @bikicodes can you provide the link to the question/answer you found please :). I am also having issues with this.